# Change Default Integer Value Of C++ Dictionary TryGetValue() Method?

Tags: dictionary, managed-c++, trygetvalue

Quick question which I fear has a short and disappointing answer but alas I shall ask anyway..
In the C++ Dictionary method TryGetValue() is there any way to change the default value that will be returned for an integer (to -1 instead for example) when the key is not present? The problem is that 0 is the default and this is not suitable because a value of 0 would make sense in the context of my program.

If not, is the ContainsKey() method that much slower? Or is it splitting hairs and nothing to worry about seeing as in all likelihood I have no choice..

Many thanks

PS I don't need to perform any hashing function (though this might be in the implementation for Dictionary anyway!), nor have any particular ordering to my collection, I just want lookup and adding to be as fast as possible. Is Dictionary a sound choice?

Comment: Do you mean Managed C++? It is not the same as C++ should be tagged as such.

Comment: I'm writing in unmanaged using Dictionary<String^, String^>^ dictionary = gcnew Dictionary<String^, String^>(); syntax... though with ints instead of string

Comment: There is no operator named `gcnew` in C++. You're using [Managed C++, or C++/CLI](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Managed_C%2B%2B_programming_language) as it is known now

Comment: Oh I see. In truth I barely use C++ generally. My apologies for the mix up.

Comment: you are definitely using managed code : [hint1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) - on this page it says clearly that the function is in .Net Framework 4.0 and  [hint2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8(v=vs.80).aspx) ... you are using gcnew wich is creating a new garbage collected object.. that means it's managed

Comment: The gcnew is a pretty big giveaway... my bad. Thanks for the tips. Any ideas on the question too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a class that inherits from [`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and override the [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) function. You could then use your own class and it would behave just as you would want it to...

Comment: That's true, perhaps I will resort to that then. Just seems like an oversight that MS don't let you set a default value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have just realised that the bool returned by the method indicates whether the value was present or not. Sorry for not noticing that before, yesterday was a long day and I blame fatigue!! Thanks again